# Drools action object member variables not set

Tags: java, drools

After firing rules, somehow the action object (`notificationObj`) member variable values are not set. However when I execute it via Junit test class it returns values as expected. But when the war gets deployed it returns null values. Can you please let m know what could be wrong?

```
List<Attribute> auxiliaryList = eventObject.getAuxiliary();
Attribute attributeObj = new Attribute();
Notification notificationObj = new Notification();

KnowledgeBase kBase = kBuilderUtility.buildKBase(resourceName, workSheetName);
StatefulKnowledgeSession kSession = kBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

FactHandle eventObjHandle = kSession.insert(eventObject);
FactHandle attributeObjHandle = kSession.insert(attributeObj);
FactHandle notificationObjHandle = kSession.insert(notificationObj);

for (Attribute attribute : auxiliaryList) {
    if (createNewNotificationObject) {
        notificationObj = new Notification();
    }
    attributeObj.setName(attribute.getName());
    attributeObj.setValue(attribute.getValue());

    kSession.update(eventObjHandle, eventObject);
    kSession.update(attributeObjHandle, attributeObj);
    kSession.update(notificationObjHandle, notificationObj);

    kSession.setGlobal("eventObj", eventObject);
    kSession.setGlobal("attributeObj", attributeObj);
    kSession.setGlobal("notificationObj", notificationObj);

    kSession.fireAllRules();

    LOGGER.debug(notificationObj.getCommunicationType());
    eventObject.getNotificationCollection().add(notificationObj);
    createNewNotificationObject = true;
}
```

The rule sheet produces DRL string as expected as given below.
Rule values at C15, header at C9:

```
rule "Rule_Evaluation_15"
when
    $eventObj: Event(eventType=="ABC", sourceSystem=="ABC")
    $attributeObj: Attribute(name=="old_status", value=="XYS")
then
     notificationObj.setMsgDescription("ABC");;
     notificationObj.setSourceSystem("XYZ");;
     notificationObj.setTemplateId("12345AB");;
     notificationObj.setCommunicationType("Email");;
     notificationObj.setLanguage("English");;
     notificationObj.setEmailAddress("test@gmail.com");;
     notificationObj.setActionRouter("SendNowRouter");;
end
```

Comment: There is no way one can say whether the Java and DRL code as shown results in rule "Rule_Evaluation_15" ever being fired. If it is not fired, all Notification properties remain null, as you have observed.

Comment: Thanks Laune.But want to understand how does it work when we execute the Junit and return exepcted results.

Comment: You'll have to examine all of the code you have NOT shown to learn the reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work perfectly fine. The incoming object had some typos which caused the rule matching to fail every time thereby causing the object to return null values.